# NodeJS: Merge two PDF files into one using the buffer obtained by reading them

Tags: node.js, pdf, npm

I am using fill-pdf npm module for filling template pdf's and it creates new file which is read from the disk and returned as buffer to callback. I have two files for which i do the same operation. I want to combine the two buffers there by to form a single pdf file which i can send back to the client. I tried different methods of buffer concatenation. The buffer can be concatenated using Buffer.concat, like,

```
var newBuffer = Buffer.concat([result_pdf.output, result_pdf_new.output]);
```

The size of new buffer is also the sum of the size of the input buffers. But still when the `newBuffer` is sent to client as response, it shows only the file mentioned last in the array.

```
res.type("application/pdf");
return res.send(buffer);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging PDFs in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41101395/merging-pdfs-in-node)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[HummusJS](https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS) supports combining PDFs using its [appendPDFPagesFromPDF](https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/wiki/Embedding-pdf#basic-page-appending) method

Example using streams to work with buffers:

```
const hummus = require('hummus');
const memoryStreams = require('memory-streams');

/**
 * Concatenate two PDFs in Buffers
 * @param {Buffer} firstBuffer 
 * @param {Buffer} secondBuffer 
 * @returns {Buffer} - a Buffer containing the concactenated PDFs
 */
const combinePDFBuffers = (firstBuffer, secondBuffer) => {
    var outStream = new memoryStreams.WritableStream();

    try {
        var firstPDFStream = new hummus.PDFRStreamForBuffer(firstBuffer);
        var secondPDFStream = new hummus.PDFRStreamForBuffer(secondBuffer);

        var pdfWriter = hummus.createWriterToModify(firstPDFStream, new hummus.PDFStreamForResponse(outStream));
        pdfWriter.appendPDFPagesFromPDF(secondPDFStream);
        pdfWriter.end();
        var newBuffer = outStream.toBuffer();
        outStream.end();

        return newBuffer;
    }
    catch(e){
        outStream.end();
        throw new Error('Error during PDF combination: ' + e.message);
    }
};

combinePDFBuffers(PDFBuffer1, PDFBuffer2);
```

Comment: Usage please, what is the type of PDFBuffer1, PDFBuffer2

Comment: @M.Abulsoud They are both [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer)s filled with binary PDF data. In my case I created the buffers using the [page.pdf()](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions) method of [Puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

Comment: Here is an example of merging pdfs from the author: https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/blob/master/tests/MergePDFPages.js

Comment: I'm trying to use this in a React component, but it seems impossible. I missing something?

Comment: @ZachEsposito Puppeteer's page.pdf() returns a Buffer

Comment: I'm getting files from firebase cloud storage like that `const [files] = await storage.bucket(bucket).getFiles(options);`
Can I iterate through this array to merge these array items? What are they? Buffers?

Answer (score 45):

As mentioned by @MechaCode, the creator has ended support for **`HummusJS`**.

So I would like to give you 2 solutions.

1. Using [node-pdftk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-pdftk) npm module

   The Following sample code uses `node-pdftk` npm module to combine
   two pdf buffers seamlessly.

   ```
   const pdftk = require('node-pdftk');

   var pdfBuffer1 = fs.readFileSync("./pdf1.pdf");
   var pdfBuffer2 = fs.readFileSync("./pdf2.pdf");

   pdftk
       .input([pdfBuffer1, pdfBuffer2])
       .output()
       .then(buf => {
           let path = 'merged.pdf';
           fs.open(path, 'w', function (err, fd) {
               fs.write(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, null, function (err) {
                   fs.close(fd, function () {
                       console.log('wrote the file successfully');
                   });
               });
           });
       });
   ```

   The requirement for node-pdftk npm module is you need to install the
   PDFtk library. Some of you may find this overhead / tedious. So I have another solution using pdf-lib library.
2. Using [pdf-lib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-lib) npm module

   ```
   const PDFDocument = require('pdf-lib').PDFDocument

   var pdfBuffer1 = fs.readFileSync("./pdf1.pdf"); 
   var pdfBuffer2 = fs.readFileSync("./pdf2.pdf");

   var pdfsToMerge = [pdfBuffer1, pdfBuffer2]

   const mergedPdf = await PDFDocument.create(); 
   for (const pdfBytes of pdfsToMerge) { 
       const pdf = await PDFDocument.load(pdfBytes); 
       const copiedPages = await mergedPdf.copyPages(pdf, pdf.getPageIndices());
       copiedPages.forEach((page) => {
            mergedPdf.addPage(page); 
       }); 
   } 

   const buf = await mergedPdf.save();        // Uint8Array

   let path = 'merged.pdf'; 
   fs.open(path, 'w', function (err, fd) {
       fs.write(fd, buf, 0, buf.length, null, function (err) {
           fs.close(fd, function () {
               console.log('wrote the file successfully');
           }); 
       }); 
   });
   ```

Personally I prefer to use pdf-lib npm module.

Comment: Arguably this is a better example for using PDF-LIB https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib#copy-pages

Comment: Be aware that pdf-lib doesn't handle encrypted pdf. If you are trying to merge encrypted pdf, it'll result in blank pages.

Answer (score 4):

Here's what we use in our Express server to merge a list of PDF blobs.

```
const { PDFRStreamForBuffer, createWriterToModify, PDFStreamForResponse } = require('hummus');
const { WritableStream } = require('memory-streams');

// Merge the pages of the pdfBlobs (Javascript buffers) into a single PDF blob                                                                                                                                                                  
const mergePdfs = pdfBlobs => {
  if (pdfBlobs.length === 0) throw new Error('mergePdfs called with empty list of PDF blobs');
  // This optimization is not necessary, but it avoids the churn down below                                                                                                                                                
  if (pdfBlobs.length === 1) return pdfBlobs[0];

  // Adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766234/nodejs-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-using-the-buffer-obtained-by-reading-them?answertab=active#tab-top                                                     
  // Hummus is useful, but with poor interfaces -- E.g. createWriterToModify shouldn't require any PDF stream                                                                                                              
  // And Hummus has many Issues: https://github.com/galkahana/HummusJS/issues                                                                                                                                              
  const [firstPdfRStream, ...restPdfRStreams] = pdfBlobs.map(pdfBlob => new PDFRStreamForBuffer(pdfBlob));
  const outStream = new WritableStream();
  const pdfWriter = createWriterToModify(firstPdfRStream, new PDFStreamForResponse(outStream));
  restPdfRStreams.forEach(pdfRStream => pdfWriter.appendPDFPagesFromPDF(pdfRStream));
  pdfWriter.end();
  outStream.end();
  return outStream.toBuffer();
};

module.exports = exports = {
  mergePdfs,
};
```

Comment: hummusJs is now un-supported by creater.

Comment: Works like a charm!, if you need to merge base64 representation of pdfs into a single one (without the usage of files) then you need to pass the pdfBlobs as this
`Buffer.from(base64String, 'base64')`