# nodejs: merging pdf streams \ buffers

Tags: node.js, pdf, stream, pdf-generation, buffer

pdf-merge provides an api for merging pdf files, but it falls short when trying to merge buffers or streams.
When trying to merge these buffers in the standard manner or via packages (aka Buffer.concat, stream-concat, buffer-concat) the result only includes the last stream instead of a merged result.

As it seems, more people encountered this issue, but no solution was provided (example :[NodeJS: Merge two PDF files into one using the buffer obtained by reading them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766234/nodejs-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-using-the-buffer-obtained-by-reading-them))

I guess this is due to the unique representation of a pdf file.

I also tried pdfkit's addContent(buffer) but the result is an empty file  and apparently it is not supported (https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/issues/417).

Did anyone experience this issue and made it work ?
We must use streams for performance issues (so mitigating via files is not an option).

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS: Merge two PDF files into one using the buffer obtained by reading them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766234/nodejs-merge-two-pdf-files-into-one-using-the-buffer-obtained-by-reading-them)

Answer (score 6):

I found `node-pdftk` to be of great use for this. By simply passing an array of buffers as `input` and then immediately turning it into `output`, you should get a combined set of PDFs.

`npm i node-pdftk`

```
const pdfs = [...] // array of PDF buffers

pdftk
  .input(pdfs)
  .output()
  .then(buf => {
    res.type('application/pdf');
    res.send(buf);
  });
```